# Idempotents which are not Murray-von Neumann equivalent to its adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

What is  an example of  a  $C^{*}$  algebra with an idempotent $e$ such that $e$ is  not Murray-von Neumann equivalent to $e^{*}$?

Comment: Can you give a definition when two (projectors?) are equivalent? The definition I found presupposes that the projectors are hermitian.

Comment: @s.harp Murray  Von neimann equivalent is defined on the space of  idempotents  of  a  ring. two idempotents e  and  f are equivalent if $e=xy, f=yx$ for two elements x, y of the ring.. By idempotent I mean $e^2=e$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An idempotent $e$ is always equivalent to $e^*$.

On the unitization of $A$, let $z=1+(e-e^*)^*(e-e^*)$. This is positive and invertible. By noticing that $z=1-e-e^*+ee^*+e^*e$, it is clear that $z$ commutes with $e$ and $e^*$, and a fortiori so does $z^{-1}$.

Let $x=ee^*\in A$, $y=e^*z^{-1}e\in A$ (recall that $A$ is an ideal in its unitization). Note that $$ze=ee^*e,\ \ \ ze^*=e^*ee^*;$$  then
$$
xy=ee^*(e^*z^{-1}e)=z^{-1}ee^*e=e,
$$
$$
yx=(e^*z^{-1}e)ee^*=z^{-1}e^*ee^*=e^*.
$$

*(I know the ideas behind this from Davidson, Proposition IV.1.1)*

**Edit:** interestingly, a byproduct of this argument is that every idempotent is the product of two positives.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very interesting answer.

Comment: what about stronger equivalent, i.e similarity or homotopy?

Comment: Every idempotent $e$ in a C*-algebra is a quasi-inverse $(pq)^\dagger$ of a unique pair of projections satisfying $||p-q||<1$, namely the left and right support projections of $e$.  Thus there will be a homotopy of projections switching $p$ and $q$ and also a symmetry switching $p$ and $q$.  So yes $e$ and $e^*$ will be both similar and homotopy equivalent.